# trigger datalist options on click event of text box

Tags: jquery, html, html-datalist

How to show or trigger the datalist options on clicking of its corresponding text box?
I have a datalist with options say 10. In chrome,a dropdown icon is shown allowing the user to know it has a dropdown list. But in firefox,icon is not available.Hence,the user may not be aware that it is a dropdown and just a text box .So i want to show the datalist options on click of that text box. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a solution might be this ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/MY7yK/3/))

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;/*remove default arrow in Chrome*/
}
.required:after {
    content: url(http://s25.postimg.org/6k40u5hcr/arrow.png);
    margin-left: -20px; 
    padding: .1em;
    pointer-events:none;/*make png cliccable*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="required"><input id="team" list="bestTeam"></span>
     <datalist id="bestTeam">
       <option value="Inter">
       <option value="Milan">
       <option value="Juve">
       <option value="Roma">
     </datalist>
   </body>
</html>
```

First of all i removed the default arrow in chrome with input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
in after element i set a small image in content property
to make the image clickable use pointer-events:none
This solution works on the latest versions of Chrome, firefox and IE
If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Answer (score 0):

That is a browser built-in feature that can't be modified. Also `datalist` isn't supported by Safari in versions lower than 12.1 nor lower versions of IE10

In order to accomplish this functionality use this polyfill: [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/#introduction). 
This will give feature support to Safari and IE- and convert the `datalist` into a regular `ul` list that you can then easily attach events to display/hide the list without loosing the autocomplete functionality.