# My made-up combobox is missing its arrow

Tags: html, combobox

I have a made-up combobox... more like a textbox with suggestions... in chrome, it has an arrow, making it like a real combobox... but this arrow is missing in mozilla. is there a way for this arrow to also appear in mozilla? I really need it as a combobox and not a drop-down list.

I have no special css for it but here is the code:

```
<input type="text" list="pilian" id="gi_classification" name="gi_classification">
<datalist id="pilian">
    <option>For Sale</option>
    <option>For Lease</option>
    <option>For Sale &amp; For Lease</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can find the answer to your question here: [trigger datalist options on click event of text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189911/trigger-datalist-options-on-click-event-of-text-box) (your question is possible duplicate).